# How to create flipping tile effect inside an app for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing an app which shows image and I want to provide important relevant information on the same image. Essentially, I want to create a flipping tile inside an app and later pin it to the start. Is it possible to have one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Radcontrols](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) Hubtile or [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) Hubtile is what you are looking for.
About creating secondary tiles on windows phone check [this article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/How-to-add-and-remove-Secondary-Tiles-in-Windows-Phone-apps).